# iOS 7 shows black background in custom animation for Navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I am using custom animation for navigation in my iOS app.

I have a subclass of `UINavigationController` in which the following methods are overridden:

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.4;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;//kCATransitionFade; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"Push"];

    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
}

- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.4;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;//kCATransitionFade; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"Pop"];

    UIViewController *poppedVC = [super popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    return poppedVC;
}
```

I don't remember the link but I had copied this code from a question in here and a little modification had worked for me.

Now when I ported my code to iOS 7 SDK, there is a black background shown while navigation.

I posted a video here: [Black background while navigation in iOS app](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJz0RDn3BMY&feature=youtu.be) to make it clear.

Note: The requirement in my app is that animation be the opposite of the default right-left and left-right when push/pop. This code was working perfectly when I was targeting iOS 5 and there was not black background/screen shown.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this? I'm stuck with the same code ..

Comment: @NoéMalzieu not really :(. I still have the same problem.

Comment: @NoéMalzieu I did something as a work around. Now the animation seems much better than previous. I'm posting an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Add in the delegate (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method) these two lines :

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.window.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, since I couldn't find a feasible solution to this problem. I did a couple of things as work around and now the animation seems to much better than previous.

I set bar tint color and background color for `UINavigationBar` to be the same.

```
UIColor *navigationBarColor = UIColorFromHexRGB(0x0473C0);    
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:navigationBarColor];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:navigationBarColor];
```

During navigation there was black space being shown on top in place of status bar.

I did this:

```
UIView *hackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];
hackView.backgroundColor = navigationBarColor;
[self.window addSubview:hackView];
```

Note that this color is the same as for the navigation bar.

I have a common background color used for all the views in the app. To remove the black background being shown during navigation, I did this:

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"viewbackground.png"];
UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];

[self.window setBackgroundColor:bgColor];
[self.window setTintColor:bgColor];
```

[Video uploaded here](http://youtu.be/8JFF4lcC_ns).

Comment: Thanks! I had the same kind of code but with bad results, I'll try it out :)
I also saw a solution using a snapshot of the screen, will try

Comment: Thank you Abdullah really nice answer. solved [UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor :D